# Tablet CPU gets too hot,Shut down Resets tablet

Tags: internal-storage, hardware, shutdown, overheating

I have a [thomson MID1002](http://www.thomson-electronics.com/index.php/products/tablets/16gb-m1002) tablet (maybe Chinese). Problem is

- Whenever I shut it down, it instead resets the tablet, thereby restarting it.
- The internal storage shows 0.0B, hence no app can be installed.
- The processor chip (CPU: ARM Cortex A9) gets too hot in idle state. I can't put my finger on it for 2 seconds.

I flashed the stock ROM successfully but problem is not yet solved. Resetting still occurs whenever I shut down, internal storage is still 0.0B, and the chip gets too hot. Is it a software level problem? 
I have added the linux shell Top command result
[image]

Comment: Can you get a shell and look at the load average, or run `top` to see if there is a big consumer?

Comment: thnk u bro, I did the top command,check the edited question, I dont think there's any big consumer, and the cpu doesnt get hot all d time.I m also not sure how HOT is normal.I usually get around 30-45C with CPUTemp application

Comment: currently I m more worried abt resetting and internal storage problem.